# WSO2 Open Source Edition Suitable for Production

Tags: wso2-api-manager

Can we use Open Source edition of WSO2 for Production. Any feature difference compare to Enterprize edition? Any API/s  limitation?

Answer (score 0):

For the opensource products such as WSO2 API Manager, there is no enterprise edition. What you have is a subscription to receive product support, continuous bug fixes and security updates via their [update tool](https://wso2.com/updates/).

For the opensource products, there will be no limitations (since you are the one responsible for the deployment) or feature differences (other than the minor improvements provided through updates).

You can use opensource products for production. However, you will not receive security and bug fixes for the already released versions. You can refer to their licenses from [here](https://wso2.com/licenses/).

On the other hand WSO2 provides cloud-based solutions such as Choreo which are available with [enterprise plans](https://wso2.com/choreo/pricing/).